# Is it possible to stack only some data series?

Tags: flot

I have a chart with 3 stacked lines. The area below each line is filled.
Now I want to add two further non-stacked lines.

Currently, I have

```
this.flotOptions.series.stack = true;
```

and use another y-axis (with the same range) for the two new lines.
However, they the all lines still are stacked.

**Is it possible to specify which data series shall be stacked?**

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Since you provided no code for us to look at (not a good idea, in my view), I'm going to have to guess you are just using an array of data points for a series and passing an array of those series to `$.plot`. Flow actually allows for an array of series *objects*, of which only one property is the data, the other properties allow you to configure the plot for that series in any way you like.

For example, [here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JMBucknall/rytzed2z/) that shows how it can be done. The relevant code is

```
$.plot("#chart", [
    { data: series1, lines: {fill: true}, label: "one" }, 
    { data: series2, lines: {fill: true}, label: "two" }, 
    { data: series3, lines: {fill: false}, label: "three" }, 
    { data: series4, lines: {fill: false}, label: "four" }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that's how I provide the data. Now, I am wondering if it is possible to stack some of the data series (but not all of them).

Comment: Use the `stack: true/false` option per data series, see this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rytzed2z/4/).